# Is it possible that a matter field has a dependent on non-radial space-like coordinate in a spacetime with spherical symmetry?

Tags: general-relativity

After the work from Breitenlohner and Freedman, we know matter fields in asymptotically AdS spacetime can be stable out of the black hole under some special conditions.

**My question:** In such a spherically symmetric spacetime, could the matter field has the non-radial variable of the coordinate? If it could be, what is the limit on it?

Suppose the metric tensor is 
$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = -f(r)\mathrm{d}t^2 + \frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{f(r)} + \frac{r^2}{L^2}\Omega_2(\theta, \phi)$$
$r \rightarrow +\infty$ is the infinite boundary, $f(r) \rightarrow  \frac{r^2}{L^2}$ as $r \rightarrow +\infty$ and $L$ is the AdS radius,  $\Omega_2$ is the 2-d spherical coordinate.

The matter field $\Phi(r,\theta)$  in question is a complex scalar field with a charge $q$ 
and the Maxwell field (1-form) reads:
 $$A = A_t(r,\theta) \mathrm{d}t^2$$

the coordinate $r$ is the radial variable and $x$ is the non-radial.

Is it possible for the set-up above?

Thank you for your time.

-------------------**Update**---------------

To avoid more confusion, rather planar AdS black hole, we consider the metric as above showed.

Perhaps my question can be changed into this one:
Provided the stable spacetime is of spherically symmetric,  if all matter fields coupling with the black hole in this spacetime should has the $SO(2)$ symmetry, and this property is equal that all matter fields haven't the non-radical space-like variable?

Comment: I updated more details, in ordinary case, the Maxwell field and scalar field taken as $A_t(r), \Phi(r)$ are OK, what about to consider them to add one more variable $x$ ?

Comment: Completely Rewrite your question : The non-radial part of the metrics is incorrect depends on $\theta, \phi$, secondly, "$r \to \infty$ is the infinite boudary" is a tautology. The expression $A_a = A_t(r,x) (\mathrm{d}t^2)_a$ is nonsense. Is your matter field $\Phi$ the source of the gravitation ? Why is it complex ? Is the Maxwell field also source of the gravitation ?

Comment: Thank @Trimok
1. I said $r \rightarrow \infty$ is to emphasize $r$ is the radical variable.
2. The notation $A_a = A_t(r,x) (\mathrm{d}t^2)_a$ is  the [Abstract index notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) introdiced by Penrose.
3. The matter field $\Phi$ is the scalar field coupling with the black hole, and since it is complex, it would take a charge $q$, further, in this circumstance, we can take the  black hole as the Reissner–Nordström black hole, so there is an electromagnetic field $A$.

Comment: Totally, in this asymptotically AdS spacetime, there are three fields: the gravity, complex scalar field and the Maxwell field. under the probe limit, we can neglect the backreaction, and matter fields decouples with the gravity field.

Comment: @Trimok To focus the problem, I revised the formulas.